# How to use subqueries without using JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

The following question is based on the student schema database provided by Oracle:

> The following sub-questions are related; make sure you know how to do the previous one before moving to the next.
>
> (a) Write a SQL statement to show section IDs and section enrollment.
>
> (b) Write a SQL statement to list all students (use the format: ,  in a single column) in sections with fewer than five students enrolled.
>
> Do not show any duplicate student names and sort the result by last name.

These questions are to be answered without the use of JOIN. Please explain how this is possible without JOIN.

Table STUDENT columns: first_name, last_name, student_id

Table ENROLLMENT columns: student_id, section_id

For 2a., I have used:

```
SELECT COUNT(section_id)
FROM enrollment
GROUP BY section_id
```

This gives me the correct result for amount of students enrolled in each section, however, when I try to use this as the subquery with:

```
SELECT last_name, SUBSRT(first_name, 0,1)
FROM student
WHERE ANY(5) < (SELECT COUNT(section_id)
                FROM enrollment
                GROUP BY section_id)
```

I receive this error:

> ```
> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> Cause:
> Action:
> Error at Line: 3 Column: 7
> ```

TABLES INVOLVED: ENROLLMENT, STUDENT

ENROLLMENT COLUMNS INVOLVED: student_id, section_id

STUDENT COLUMNS INVOLVED: student_id, first_name, last_name

This question was asked with assumed knowledge of the student schema database provided by Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Hint: HAVING clause.

Comment: can you please show you table with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using two nested sub-selects. The inner one is selecting sections with less than 5 students enrolled. The outer one selects student_ids from these sections.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT last_name, SUBSTR(first_name, 0, 1)
FROM student
WHERE student_id IN (
    SELECT student_id
    FROM enrollment
    WHERE section_id IN (
        SELECT section_id FROM enrollment GROUP BY section_id HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
    )
)
ORDER BY lat_name
```

Note that `HAVING`, unlike `WHERE`, is performed after `GROUP BY` and can use aggregate functions.

If all the students have different names, the `DISTINCT` keyword is not necessary. It would be necessary if we used JOINs, since this would duplicate student rows.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the point why you don't want JOIN, but you can do follwing, with a subquery and exists

```
CREATE TABLe student(student_id int, first_name varchar2(50),last_name varchar2(50))
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(1,'A','B')
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(2,'C','D')
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(3,'E','F')
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(4,'G','H')
```

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES(5,'I','J')
```

```
CREATE tABLe enrollment(student_id int, section_id int)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (1,1)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (1,2)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (1,3)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (2,2)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (3,2)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (4,2)
```

```
INSERT INTO  enrollment VALUES (5,2)
```

```
SELECT last_name, SUBSTR(first_name, 0,1)
FROM student st
             
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM enrollment WHERE student_id = st.student_id AND section_id 
  IN (  SELECT section_id
                FROM enrollment
                GROUP BY section_id HAVING COUNT(section_id) < 5))
```

| LAST_NAME | SUBSTR(FIRST_NAME,0,1) |
| --- | --- |
| B | A |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VjxjimSp)

Answer (score 1):

If I follow you correctly, no need for nested subqueries here.

Starting from the students table, we can use `exists` to check if they enrolled in at least one section that has less than 5 participants.

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (
    select 1
    from enrollment e
    group by section_id
    having 
        -- less than 5 participants
        count(*) < 5
        -- including the current student
        and max(case when e.student_id = s.student_id then 1 else 0 end) = 1
)
```

The trick is to group by section, and to use the `having` clause for filtering.